# <FormSettings> isn't loading up on the new outlook

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have an add-in which uses `<FormSettings>` for the UI, this add-in works fine in the current owa but it isn't loading up on "The new Outlook"

[image]

[image]

Is this expected ? Or is this happening because the new outlook is still in beta.?

Current OWA:
[image]

New Outlook:
[image]

Here is the manifest xml snippet of the add-in:

```
<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
</Hosts>
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
        <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
<FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
        <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://<url-i-replaced>/index.html"/>
            <RequestedHeight>210</RequestedHeight>
        </DesktopSettings>
        <TabletSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://<url-i-replaced>/index.html"/>
            <RequestedHeight>210</RequestedHeight>
        </TabletSettings>
        <PhoneSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://<url-i-replaced>/index.html"/>
        </PhoneSettings>
    </Form>
</FormSettings>
<Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
</Rule>
<DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
```

No changes are done in the manifest xml from last 2 years.

This issue is observed on Edge, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about where your Add-in is expected to be seen and where it is not seen in new Outlook? If you could include the text of your FormSettings node that would also be helpful. Have you recently changed your manifest file? Finally, please let us know if this issue present across all browsers or only a specific one!

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have updated the question, please check if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot and manifest shows the issue - the style of Add-in you are using was deprecated and is not supported in the new Outlook Web. You should upgrade your Add-in to use the [Add-in Commands model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook) to continue to work in Outlook Web.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any documentation of this being deprecated ?

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/make-your-add-ins-available-in-the-office-ribbon/  discusses the deprecation.